# compiling pango: undefined reference to `hb_ft_face_create'

Tags: makefile, configure, pango

I've been trying to compile pango-1.38.1

configure was fine however there is a link error during make:

```
Making all in pango-view
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/build/pango-1.38.1/pango-view'
  CCLD     pango-view
../pango/.libs/libpangoft2-1.0.so: undefined reference to `hb_ft_face_create'
../pango/.libs/libpangoft2-1.0.so: undefined reference to `hb_ft_face_create_cached'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [pango-view] Error 1
```

Harfbuzz and package config is installed/located in

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/harfbuzz.pc
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Where can I find `hb_ft_face_create`?

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: If all you need is `pango` without the viewer/examples/etc., edit the Makefile, find the line starting with `SUBDIRS=` and remove everything except `pango`.